# Is the code that produces the SDSS DR16Q quasar catalogue available?

Tags: quasars, sloan-dss

I'm curious if it's available to investigate (from my question in the title), or even better, modify and re-run. See [SDSS DR16Q quasar catalogue](https://www.sdss4.org/dr17/algorithms/qso_catalog/).

Not the data itself, that's in a fits file. The code they ran to produce the fits file.

The part I'm most interested in are the K corrections.

Comment: Did you ask the authors of the catalogue?

Comment: I emailed the SDSS helpdesk

Answer (score 3):

From helpdesk@sdss:

"The code repository that Eleanor Lyke referenced in the DR16Q Value added catalog (VAC) paper on page 5 of ApJS (2020) 250 8 is:  "The python code for generating DR16Q is available publicly” at

```
https://github.com/bradlyke/dr16q
```

Many thanks to the team, original author, and planetmaker.

Comment: Very nice that you were able to self-answer this question - and to document that answer here